# Favicon displays in IE but not Firefox and Chrome

Tags: graphics, cross-browser, favicon

I recently added a 16px by 16 px favicon.ico file to my htdocs directory.

The results are as follows:

IE - correctly displays in address bar, tab bar, and bookmarks bar

Chrome - correctly displays in bookmarks bar

Firefox - correctly displays in bookmarks bar

I'd like to have my favicon display in the address bar and tab bar of Chrome and Firefox, what do I need to do to accomplish this?

Thanks?

Comment: That _should_ work - are you sure you're looking in the right place? In Chrome, favicons don't display in the address bar any more, only in the tab bar. I'd have to double-check, but I suspect the same would apply in Firefox.

Comment: They are not in the tab bar either, what gives?

Comment: I downloaded a favicon (other site's) and noticed that they had images displayed in different layers of the .ico file.  Could this be an issue.  I just have one layer at 16px by 16px?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Comment: Chrome is good - I needed to add in the link to the xhtml...IE does not need this...trying firefox now

Comment: Good to go in Firefox as well.  Displays in the address bar.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the location into the xhtml

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644684/do-you-have-to-include-link-rel-icon-href-favicon-ico-type-image-x-icon), simply adding the **favicon.ico** file to your site's root directory is the discouraged method of adding a favorite icon to your site. The encouraged method is to add the following lines within the < head>...< /head> section of your html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211206/html5-link-rel-shortcut-icon) suggests that the *rel="shortcut icon"* method is being replaced by the *rel="icon"* method, but to be safe for compatibility reasons I like to include both, as well as put the favicon.ico file in the site's root directory; this way all my bases are covered for all browsers.