# HTML5 `<link rel="shortcut icon" />`

Tags: html, favicon

The [WHATWG document](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-rel) for HTML5 says that the `rel` attribute must contain values that are space-separated, and then it gives a table of allowed values.

> The attribute's value must be a set of space-separated tokens. The [allowed keywords and their meanings](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#linkTypes)...

The list of allowed keywords for the `link` element does not include `shortcut`, but it does include `icon`. So I'm looking at the all-too-well-known tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

and wondering if it is HTML5-compliant. Should I remove the keyword `shortcut` from this tag throughout my Website?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From the same WHATWG document:

> For historical reasons, the icon keyword may be preceded by the
>   keyword "shortcut". If the "shortcut" keyword is present, it must be
>   come immediately before the icon keyword and the two keywords must be
>   separated by only a single U+0020 SPACE character.

Comment: But if I want to move forward, would it be safe to remove `shortcut `?

Comment: It's unlikely any future mainstream browser will require it, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @TestSubject: Yeah, you should be fine to simply use `icon`.

Answer (score 21):

#### Update

According to [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel):

> The *shortcut* link type is often seen before icon, but this link type
> is non-conforming, ignored and web authors must not use it anymore.

Also, I don't see any references of *shortcut* in the [W3Schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp), so I think it's better to leave it out.

Comment: w3schools != W3C

Comment: @pablo Perhaps you might want to edit your answer to improve your references?  Perhaps simply remove the reference to w3schools?  You might get more upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

I have tested this code on Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Internet explorer, and Microsoft Edge, and the only browser that didn't work was Edge. When add Favorite from a page made on harddrive ex c:\temp\test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"><!-- Never caches the page -->
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="icon_32.ico">
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer with test results is excellent - you could improve it by adding a little more info to your test info: browser versions, operating system, and perhaps an image of the browser tab for each of the browsers you tested to show the results?

Answer (score 3):

Although it is still in its experimental stage (because HTML5 dev is ongoing), the
[w3.org HTML5 Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options) 
is a good online tool you can check out. I used it extensively about 6 months ago and it always gave back accurate HTML5 syntax reports.

Comment: I found the Markup Validator in this answer useful.  As of 2020-12-11 it is functional and did a great job of showing me warnings and errors of all types. Yet it did not flag the following line as a warning or error: <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.jpg" />  Perhaps this information would be better as a comment to the post rather than an answer.