# How to set up a favicon?

Tags: favicon

I am trying to do a very simple preliminary exercise to setting up a website which is creating a favicon.

This is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
</html>
```

But it is not working - can anyone please assist?
I've saved the file favicon.ico on the same level as my html file (on a subdirectory).

Many thanks

Comment: did you add it to your html? 
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> and make sure it is on the root

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. That is the extent of my code in my question - is it right?

Comment: looks right. make sure the icon exists where your href is pointing at.

Comment: Nope, nothing happening.

Answer (score 86):

With the introduction of (i|android|windows)phones, things have changed, and to get a correct and complete solution that works on any device is really time-consuming.

You can have a peek at https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility or http://caniuse.com/#search=favicon to get an idea on the best way to get something that works on any device.

You should have a look at 
http://realfavicongenerator.net/
to automate a large part of this work, and probably at https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet to understand how it works (even if this latter resource hasn't been updated in a loooong time).

One complete solution requires to add to you header the following (with the corresponding pictures and files, of course) :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="browserconfig.xml">
```

In June 2016, [RealFaviconGenerator claimed that](https://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/new-favicon-package-less-is-more/) the following 5 lines of code were supporting as many devices as the previous 18 lines:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Comment: Looks too complicated. I don't think this is needed anymore.

Comment: @guettli Ok… Do you have a source to back this up, or some experiment? It's not because it *looks complicated* that this is not the right way to do it, or is it? What is your solution?

Comment: @Clenent. There is an other answer to this question (by User Schw2iizer) which is one one HTML line. If you think more lines are needed, then please explain why more is needed.

Comment: @guettli ? The first sentence of my answer explain why more is needed. "With the introduction of (i|android|windows)phones, things have changed, and to get a correct and complete solution that works on any device is really time-consuming." That one line with one `.ico` file does not work on every device. Cf. https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet , that I refer to in my answer as well.

Comment: if I read "to x for Android 2.1" then I think "this is not used any more". I do not plan to support Android 2.1 and iOS of the same age.

Comment: @guettli Ok, maybe you should read a couple of lines after this. Have a look at https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?protocol=http&site=thomas-guettler.de%2F for yourself:  iOS Safari, Android Chrome, and some other are missing. I'm not saying it's a must have (you may obviously not care about those devices, or think that it's their problem and not yours), I'm just saying that having "correct and complete solution that works on any device is really time-consuming.". Feel free not to use it, but writing "not needed anymore" is incorrect.

Comment: you are right. If you want to support all devices, then one line is not enough.

Comment: @Clément some apps use icons you might not expect them to.  For instance, Chrome will use the Apple icons because, presumably, Google realized Apple had already set the standard.  So the list may be more complete than you think.  https://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/android-chrome-and-its-favicon/

Answer (score 52):

I use this on my site and it works great.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a very simple method to set a favicon, which had been around for a long time AFAIK.
Place the `favicon.ico` file in the default location. 
i.e

```
http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico
```

This works in almost every browser without a `<link>` tag.
However, this works only if it is an `*.ico` file. PNGs and other formats still have to be linked with a `<link>` tag

Comment: FYI - The W3C discourages this method citing that it "is inconsistent with some principles of Web architecture". https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Answer (score 8):

Below given some information about fav Icon

**What Is FavIcon?**
   FavIcon is nothing but small image which appears top left along with the application address bar title.Standard size specification for favicon.ico is 16 by 16 pixel. Please see below attached figure.

[image]

**How It Works ?** 
   Usually we add our FavIcon.ico image in the route solution folder and automatically application picks it while running. But most of the time we might have to use below both link reference.

```
               <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico"/>
               <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Some browser expect one (rel="icon") Some other browser expect other  rel="shortcut icon"

   **Type=”image/x-icon” OR Type=”image/ico”:** once expect exact ico image and one expect any image even formatted from .jpg or .pn ..etc.

   We have to use above two tags to the common pages like – Master page , Main frame which is getting used in all the pages

Answer (score 6):

you could take a look at the [w3 how to](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon), i think you will find it helpful

your link tag attribute should be `rel="icon"`

Comment: I've looked at w3 how to but to no avail. What do you mean my link tag should be rel = "icon"? that and not link rel = "shortcut icon"?

Comment: The "w3 how to" link seems to be for Html4 as profile isn't supported in Html5 so I don't think that link should be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

`rel="shortcut icon"` should be `rel="icon"`

Source: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

Comment: The most crazy thing has happened now...I have the favicon from this website (i.e. stackoverflow.com) somehow stuck on my website - How did this happen!

Comment: What is the URL of the favicon file in the `<link>` tag?

Comment: My code is still the same i.e.    {<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
</html>}

Comment: But the precise URL is file:///C:/Users/Emi/Desktop/Zedius%20website/favicon.ico

Comment: @user2694332, there is a `semi-colon` before the `<link>` tag, please remove it. Also change the value of the `rel` attribute to `icon` (`rel="icon"`). Rest of the code looks good and should work fine.

Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/q/6644684/1654121

Answer (score 1):

From experience of my favicon.ico not appearing, I am sharing my experience. You can't get it to show until you put your website on a host, therefore, try put it on a localhost using XAMPP - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html. This is how the favicon appears and like others recommended, change:

`rel="shortcut icon"`

to
    `rel="icon"`

Also this way .png favicons can be used for slickness.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please avoid code-only answer by adding a text describing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my site, I use this:

```
<!-- for FF, Chrome, Opera -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">

<!-- for IE -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicons/favicon.ico" >
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicons/favicon.ico"/>
```

To simplify your life, use this favicons generator http://realfavicongenerator.net

Answer (score 0):

**This method is recommended**

```
<link rel="icon" 
  type="image/png" 
  href="/somewhere/myicon.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try put this in the head of the document:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I use this https://realfavicongenerator.net/ to generate all the possible favicons scenarios and it is free.