# What is the best way to load a favicon for modern web browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not worried about all the devices, just modern browsers - Chrome, FF, Safari, IE.

I read

[How to set-up a favicon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301745/how-to-set-up-a-favicon)

and the two ways I see for just browsers are:

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='_images/favicon.ico'/>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="_imagers/favicon.ico">
```

Previously I had been using JavaScript to dynamically load my favicon but Chrome will hit my server for the default location producing an error ...

And I don't want it doing this ...

so I'm going to do it the standard HTML way.

Answer (score 1):

[Blog by Daniel Schwarz](https://sympli.io/blog/2017/02/15/heres-everything-you-need-to-know-about-favicons-in-2017/)  has explained the proper way to use the favicon for most of the modern web browser. I refer to this article. Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the favicon.ico file in the site's source folder and Browsers will know how to get it, and browsers aren't the only thing that will request favicon's - many crawlers and other applications do too.