# Get `favicon.ico` error, but can not find it in the code

Tags: webstorm

When I run my project in browser I get the "can not find `favicon.ico`" error in browser console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   :8080/favicon.ico

[image]

But when I search for `favicon` in whole project in WebStorm it finds nothing:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is normal. No matter if you declared it or not in your code, Chrome will try will try to fetch favicon.ico at the root of your site to display it in your tab. In your case it will try to fetch: `http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico`

All browsers will do this except SeaMonkey according to [Wikipedia article on Favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

In the old days, this was the standard way of personalizing the browser icon. Now there is a ton of possible icons you can set for various devices: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768184/1375487

Also, you can check this answer as it suggests ways to prevent that auto-fetch: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/34572

In any case, the best practice would be to set a favicon.ico for your project.

Answer (score 6):

[`favicon.ico`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) is the icon on the title bar in your website.

Browser did not find it in your website.

You should provide it to your `index.html`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
```

The path you can change by your case.