# How can I remove the React App symbol and name or the "Website created using create-react-app"?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have deployed my website with firebase hosting. Everytime I go the site, there's still the name React App on the tabs of my browser. Do I have to purchase a domain name to get rid of it?

Comment: Are you looking for [favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18301745/2873538)? See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp) for `<title>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply go to the `/public` folder of your react app and change the `<title> React App </title>` in `index.html` file to whatever the title of your website is.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the title of the `index.html` page in the public directory. And for the customizing the icon, you can change the favicon also located in the public directory.

Answer (score 1):

in public folder edit manifest.json file

"short_name": "your_app_name"
"name": "Your Tag Line"

for images just upload your images with same name for good result.
Hope this answer will be helpful.

Comment: "short_name": "Your_APP_Name"