# Is it possible to set a page icon for a webpage in HTML?

Tags: html

Every website you see now has a custom icon. But how could you set an icon like that in HTML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set-up a favicon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301745/how-to-set-up-a-favicon)

Comment: [that is already answered here ///](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

I assume **favicon**, the icon in the address bar of the browser and on the left in google search.  You need to assign them, something like this

```html
<head>
...
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/img/favicon.svg" sizes="120x120">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon-512x512.png" sizes="512x512">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/jpg" href="/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
...
</head>
```

Comment: Note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment:  I have corrected it.  I recall adding them when yandex was rejecting the pages because it didn't like the favicons.  It turned out that it wanted the first favicon to be 32x32

Comment: The question is a duplicate and will be closed eventually. You should vote to close it as a duplicate, too.