# Unfortunately, my code to integrate a favicon doesn't work

Tags: html

I don't understand why the following code doesn't work and doesn't display a favicon
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"></html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pizza&Pasta Lina</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
     <header class="header">
        <a href="" class="logo">Pizza&Pasta Lina</a>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">Speisekarte</a>
            <a href="">Bilder</a>
            <a href="">Kontakt</a>
        </nav>



     </header>
    

</body>
</html>
```

I tried many Methods to include the favicon but none worked.
I hope you can help me quickly.

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when the page is loaded, is a request made for that icon?  What is the server's response?  In what way does the code fail?

Comment: Currently the website is not online but only locally on my PC and the favicon is simply not displayed. However, the old one that I had before is displayed even though I have removed the code. This problem only exists in Chrome and Opera

Comment: *"the favicon is simply not displayed"* - Then now is the time to debug a bit further and narrow down the problem.  If you're not familiar with your browser's development/debugging tools, this is a great time to start.  Specifically you'll want to open the network tab of those tools and perform a full-reload of the page (usually Ctrl-F5).  On the network tab you can observe all of the requests being made and the servers' responses.  When you do this, is a request made for the icon?  What is the server's response?

Comment: That's definitely not the problem, I had the same code and the old image worked there too

Comment: *"That's definitely not the problem"* - So then you've performed this debugging and confirmed the response from the server?  In your browser's debugging tools, what specifically was that response?

Comment: Yes, there were only other inquiries there

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Please understand that nobody else can see your screen from here.  Take some time and update the question to include relevant debugging information that you have observed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up a favicon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301745/how-to-set-up-a-favicon)

Comment: no i dont know how to use the debug function

Comment: @Heizi: *"i dont know how to use the debug function"* - Again, can you clarify what specifically you mean by that?  You've [already indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78122335/unfortunately-my-code-to-integrate-a-favicon-doesnt-work#comment137726919_78122335) that you have performed additional debugging and observed a specific result.  Though you have yet to share any information about that result.  Please clarify.

Comment: I have no idea how this works so someone would have to explain it to me

Comment: @Heizi: So you're now indicating that you haven't used your browser's debugging tools and that you've simply been lying about it this whole time?  That is certainly counterproductive to solving the problem.  If you're not familiar with your browser's development/debugging tools, now is a great time to start.  Often (e.g. in Chrome) those tools are accessed by pressing F12.  Your favorite search engine can also help you identify and learn about your browser's development/debugging tools.  You are encouraged to try.  Observing actual information about the problem is far more useful than lying.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve not seen this problem with any of the over 1200 pages in my website; the relevant code in the header is

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="«insert correct URL here»">
```

Comment: what kind of URL should I put there I only have an image file

Comment: On mine, the file is a .ico, but I've heard suggestions that .png works. The URL in your sample code is fine; what's probably not fine is the `rel="icon"`, and the `type="image/x-icon"` isn't necessary.

Comment: `<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/images/icons/site.ico">` is more-or-less what I've got.

Comment: [W3Schools suggests that your code is OK](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_favicon.asp), modulo the correct path for the icon. There's a table on that page that indicates what they believe to be the current supported formats for the favicon, as well - however, I've occasionally found that W3Schools is _wrong_, so my advice is to test anything you do on their advice.

Comment: In looking for a better site than W3Schools, Google found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301745/how-to-set-up-a-favicon - I've VTC on that basis.