# Changing Navbar color for Bootstrap Yeti theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to using Bootstrap Version 3 an I am trying to change the default navbar color of the Bootstrap `Yeti` theme, http://bootswatch.com/yeti/, for my ASP web application in VS 2013. I downloaded the `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` files and copied them to my project.

I want to change the navbar background color to `green: 93c951` and the navbar text to `blue: 0f74bc.`

I have followed the instructions here [Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3) for the correct answer but the navbar color remains the same when I change the `.navbar-default` colour settings among other navbar setting changes. I make the changes to the `bootstrap.css` file under the `Content` folder that was made when I created my Visual Studio Web Forms application.

What do I need to do to make these changes?

### Site.Master

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Ecoline</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, it might be that the original bootstrap styles are overwriting your custom styles. Try replacing/deleting the styles you downloaded from Bootstrap – or use `!important`, if you must.

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #93c951 !important;
    border-color: #222222;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: blue;
}


// Also don't forget to change the hover styles as well

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: blue;
    background-color: #93c951 !important;
}   


// And the brand colour

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done as you have suggested to the bootstrap.css. No change. Do I need to do the same for the min.css?

Comment: If you've got the main bootstrap you shouldn't need the min.css, try getting rid of it.

Comment: Still no change. Going through the css to check if additional changes are needed.

Comment: Could you please post the head part of your html below the doctpye declaration please. Might have something to do with the ordering.

Comment: Huh, you don't import your stylesheets like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="">` okay. Do you use any other css files?

Comment: I created a Webforms application using VS 2013. I have NOT added any code to the header. All that code including that line <link... was auto-generated by Visual Studio, not me. Try it yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644684/do-you-have-to-include-link-rel-icon-href-favicon-ico-type-image-x-icon. VS generated another stylesheet named Site.css but it does not style the navbar.

Comment: Hmm, Instead of putting you CSS in another file try inlining it like so;
  `<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #93c951;">`