# Favicon Link Not Working

Tags: html, favicon

This is my code...

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://pasteboard.co/1PSjEGSk.png"/>
```

What can be done to make the favicon appear?

Comment: go to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644684/do-you-have-to-include-link-rel-icon-href-favicon-ico-type-image-x-icon

Comment: make sure you have cleared the cache and then open link http://pasteboard.co/1PSjEGSk.png in order to download the ico to your pc. Restart your server and check again. Should work

Comment: Favicons are heavily cached, try the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

See example:

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'>
```

"images" your directory path

Convart .png to .ico file using this website http://convertico.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
```

or

Simply put a file named favicon.ico in the webroot, make sure to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your html should be `rel="icon"`

Also make sure you have cleared the cache of your browser and then open link http://pasteboard.co/1PSjEGSk.png in order to download the ico to your pc. Restart your server and check again. Should work.

Also save this ico to the root of your application as favicon.ico so that all browsers can find it

Check also [w3c specs](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) on how to add the favicon.ico to your site