# Django Favicon issue

Tags: django, favicon

what ever i try to do i can't get the favicon to show up, when i look it up in the view source tab it loads up but won't appear in the tab icon position.

i'm importing it in the html like so:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/index.css" %}"/>
<link rel="Favicon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/icon.png' %}"/>
```

i set the django staticfile_dirs like so:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join('static'),
    os.path.join('static/images'),
    ]
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `rel="icon"`? What happens if you visit the URL in the browser?

Comment: when i visit the url it loads the img in a new tab

Comment: omg, it worked when i mage it rel="icon", tnx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **`.ico`** format instead of **`.png`** format and **`rel="shortcut icon"`** or **`rel="icon"`**

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `rel="…"` attribute should be [**`icon`** [mdn webdocs]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types#icon), not <s>`Favicon`</s>:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/icon.png' %}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image loads in the browser, you need to have the favicon link be `rel="icon"` rather than `rel="Favicon"`.

See [Do you have to include <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6644684/2800876)

Additionally, you can add a URL route called "favicon.ico" that returns your file.

If your image doesn't load, there is a problem with your static asset serving: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/