# Unable to use variable in the codebehind in the aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to get a custom favicon loaded for my page based on information gathered in the codebehind. I have a public string property `ClientFavicon` that is being populated correctly in the codebehind for my aspx file, but it seems I'm unable to use it. Here's what my aspx file looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" CodeBehind="page.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="project.namespace" EnableViewState="True" Async="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="<%=ClientFavicon%>" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    ...
    other head elements
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    other page elements
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

And the codebehind:

```
namespace project.namespace
{
    public class myclass
    {
        public string ClientFavicon { get; set; }

        private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ... 
           other code
           ...

           LoadClientFavicon();
        }

        private void LoadClientFavicon()
        {
            var clientFolder = "/images/client/";
            var favicon = string.Empty;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                favicon = HttpContext.Current.Session[Global.SESSION_GLOBAL_CLIENT_FAVICON] != null
                    ? HttpContext.Current.Session[Global.SESSION_GLOBAL_CLIENT_FAVICON].ToString()
                    : "favicon.ico";
                ClientFavicon = clientFolder + favicon;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run this, I get no favicon and the following 400 error in the browser devtools Network tab:

```
https://website.url/aspxpage/%3C%=ClientFavicon%%3E
```

So it looks to me like it doesn't recognize what's in the link as a variable, just as text.

For the favicon link element, I've tried with no success: using single quotes instead of double, removing the equals sign, and adding `runat="server"`.

I've also tried placing a snippet `<% var test = ClientFavicon; %>` at the top of the aspx page and set a breakpoint, the `test` variable has the right data. I was also unable to get `test` to work in the href with all of the syntax trial and error above.

Lastly I've tried moving the method populating ClientFavicon out of the codebehind and into a `<% %>` block at the top of the page before the `<head>` tag and using a variable there, but I get the same result.

I've looked at a handful of other StackOverflow posts related to this and I'm not sure what else to try or if I'm missing something.

Comment: you're not showing enough code.. where is variable defined?

Comment: what is `ClientFavIcon` is it string?  According to the code it is a property of the page class.. show your code.

Comment: Your `CodeBehind` (CodeBehind="page.aspx.cs") and `Inherits` (Inherits="project.namespace") property values seem weird, are those the correct values? _"use the Inherits and CodeFile attributes to link the code-behind file to the .aspx file. In this example, the Inherits attribute indicates the MyCodeBehind class and the CodeFile attribute indicates the path to the language-specific file that contains the class."_ ... [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page?view=netframework-4.8.1#examples)

Comment: it is a public string property in the codebehind, i mention in the beginning. I can edit the code for it into the question

Comment: "page.aspx.cs" and "project.namespace" are obfuscated from their actual names

Comment: @TMcKeown i edited it in already. The variable ClientFavicon loads the correct value, I can see it when i set breakpoints

Comment: it should work.. so you must not be showing us something or you are getting error you are unaware of.

Comment: looks like this is a homework assignment?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644684/do-you-have-to-include-link-rel-icon-href-favicon-ico-type-image-x-icon

Comment: this is not a homework assignment, also not sure what the relevance is of that linked question. I have a default favicon in the root dir of the site already if that's what you mean

Comment: its been awhile for aspx for me...  the async=true on the page make any difference?

Comment: removing it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker found that wrapping the `link` in an asp placeholder would work Since the `<head>` has `runat="server"`:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <link href="<%=ClientFavicon%>" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the link like this:

```
<link href=<%=ClientFavicon%> rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

And then including the quotes as part of the variable:

```
ClientFavicon = "\"" + clientFolder + favicon + "\"";
```

You might also need to set *the entire `link` entity*:

```
<%=ClientFavicon%>
```

and then in the code-behind:

```
var q = "\"";
ClientFavicon = $"<link href={q}{clientFolder}{favicon}{q} rel={q}shortcut icon{q} type={q}image/x-icon{q} />";
```

And since this is Web Forms where you might be using something too old for string interpolation:

```
ClientFavicon = string.Format("<link href={0}{1}{2}{0} rel={0}shortcut icon{0} type={0}image/x-icon{0} />", "\"", clientFolder, favicon);
```

*(I find the format placeholders are much more readable than escaped quotes or verbatim strings for including the quote characters, but that's a personal preference.)*